# Show video in second window (UWP C#)

Tags: c#, uwp

I have an app I'm working on and I want one window to be the controller and the other window to be the video player view.

The purpose of this is to control the video playing from one window I can look at on my laptop while the video plays on a projector.  Eventually I want to set it up so I can have a set of 16 videos I can trigger using the keyboard to play in the video player view, stopping the currently playing video when I press a key associated with a particular video (chosen through a picker) and starting the new video.

Please note, if there is a better language and/or system for creating this Windows application, I am open to any suggestions beyond what I am asking.

Here is my MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Core;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Core;
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace VideoSamplePlayer
{

    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        int newViewID = 0;

        Window VideoPlayerWindow;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (newViewID == 0) {
                var myView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();

                await myView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                {
                    Frame newFrame = new Frame();
                    newFrame.Navigate(typeof(VideoPlayer), null);

                    Window.Current.Content = newFrame;
                    Window.Current.Activate();
                    VideoPlayerWindow = Window.Current;

                    newViewID = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
                });

                await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewID, ViewSizePreference.UseMinimum);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="VideoSamplePlayer.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:VideoSamplePlayer"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Open Video Output" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,55,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="52" Width="173" Click="Button_Click"/>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Here is my VideoPlayer.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.Media.Core;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.Pickers;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace VideoSamplePlayer
{
    public sealed partial class VideoPlayer : Page
    {           
        public VideoPlayer()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
        private async void pickFileButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            // Create and open the file picker
            FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
            openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
            openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mkv");
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".avi");

            StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
            if (file != null)
            {
                mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file);
                mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.RealTimePlayback = true;
                mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.Play();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my VideoPlayer.xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="VideoSamplePlayer.VideoPlayer"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:VideoSamplePlayer"
    xmlns:mediacore="using:Windows.Media.Core"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation = "Vertical" >

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button x:Name="pickFileButton" Content="Pick video" Margin="0,0,0,10" Click="pickFileButton_Click"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <MediaPlayerElement x:Name="mediaPlayerElement" 
                                AutoPlay="False" Margin="5" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                Height="300" 
                                AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I want to move the file picker button to the MainPage, but still have the video output in the VideoPlayer.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Ironically enough; this was basically my Win32 GUI project in college... No idea as to the best way to do it in anything modern (especially UWP which restricts you a *lot*). I would recommend at least going to WPF where you can get away with more.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET can you give me some pointers as to where to start to do this in WPF, please?

Comment: I wish I could; like I said I did it in straight Win32. If you can get two windows to display at once though it should be fairly simple from there... A full answer would likely be too broad for an SO question. Try some things and ask again when you run into a more specific problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took a bit of playing around, but finally worked out a solution! The trick is to use a custom event... and the tricky part is the fact that we are playing around with multiple threads (each window is running in its own thread).

Basically, we move your button and its handler to the MainPage, but leave the lines interacting with the video player on the `VideoPlayer` page. Then we need to declare a custom event that allows the MainPage to tell the `VideoPlayer` that a video was selected, and pass the selected video to the `VideoPlayer` page. Finally the `VideoPlayer` page can take care of setting up the source and details for the actual `MediaPlayerElement` that it contains, and actually play the video.

Lets take a look at each part:

Start by declaring your custom event on the `MainPage`:

```
public delegate void VideoSelectedHandler(object sender, VideoSelectionArgs e);
public event VideoSelectedHandler VideoSelected;

private void RaiseVideoSelectedEvent(MediaSource source)
{         
    // Ensure that something is listening to the event.
    if (this.VideoSelected != null)
    {
        // Create the args, and call the listening event handlers.
        VideoSelectionArgs args = new VideoSelectionArgs(source);
        this.VideoSelected(this, args);
    }
}
```

You will also need to declare the class for the event arguments (and appropriately, it inherits from `EventArgs`. You can declare it in the same file (but outside of the `MainPage` class) or in a different file:

```
public class VideoSelectionArgs : EventArgs
{
    public MediaSource Source { get; private set; }

    public VideoSelectionArgs(MediaSource source)
    {
        this.Source = source;
    }
}
```

Next, we need the `VideoPlayer` page to subscribe to the event, so that it is listening for the event being raised. Add the event handler to the `VideoPlayer` page:

```
public void VideoSelected(object sender, VideoSelectionArgs e)
{
    mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.Source = e.Source;
    mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.RealTimePlayback = true;
    mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.Play();
}
```

Note that this is the code responsible for setting up the `MediaPlayerElement`, and accepts a `MediaSource` as the argument from the event.

Next have the `VideoPlayer` page subscribe to the `MainPage`'s event. Inside of your `Button_Click` event handler on the `MainPage`, we need to add two lines:

```
Frame newFrame = new Frame();
newFrame.Navigate(typeof(VideoPlayer), null);

// These are the two new lines... the others are shown for reference of where to place these.
VideoPlayer videoPlayerPage = newFrame.Content as VideoPlayer;
this.VideoSelected += videoPlayerPage.VideoSelected;

Window.Current.Content = newFrame;
Window.Current.Activate();
VideoPlayerWindow = Window.Current;
```

Now, you could simply call this event from the `pickFileButton_Click` handler (now on the `MainPage`, and then pass in the `MediaSource` obtained from the `FileOpenPicker`... but this is where you can get into trouble (and what took me the longest to figure out).

We have to remember that each window is running on its own thread. Even if you call code from the other window, that code is still running on the thread it was called from. This means that if you simply do the above, the code will compile and run, but when you try selecting a video file, you will get a run-time error with a message saying that a resource was marshalled on a different thread.

The solution to this is to schedule the work of getting that video file on **the same thread as the second window is running on**. So, we need to make two more modifications to accomplish this.

Firstly, we have the concept of a `Dispatcher`. Each Control has one. You already used the `Dispatcher`associated with the new view (which you declared with `var myView`. This same `Dispatcher` needs to be used to schedule the video file work, so we need to maintain a reference to it. Simply add a property to your `MainPage`:

```
CoreApplicationView VideoPlayerView { get; set; }
```

And adjust your view creation to create the new view to that property, instead of `var myView`:

```
VideoPlayerView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();

await VideoPlayerView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
…
```

Finally, we can set up the `pickFileButton_Click` handler. Move your button (no modifications needed in the XAML of the button itself) to your `MainPage.xaml`. Then move your click handler to the MainPage as well, but with the following two modifications:

- Replace the code referencing the `mediaPlayerElement` (which is now in the custom event handler on the `VideoPlayer` page). With a call to raise the custom event.
- Wrap all of the code into another scheduling to run on the thread of second window, by using that same dispatcher.

The modified event handler, now on the `MainPage`, looks like this:

```
private async void pickFileButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Schedule the work here on the same thread as the VideoPlayer window,
    //    so that it has access to the file and MediaSource to play.
    await this.VideoPlayerView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
    {
        // Create and open the file picker
        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mkv");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".avi");

        StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (file != null)
        {
            MediaSource sourceFromFile = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file);

            // Raise the event declaring that a video was selected.
            this.RaiseVideoSelectedEvent(sourceFromFile);
         }
    });
}
```

And that should do it! I did test the code, and got it to run successfully with a real video file on my computer.

Hope that helps!

The full code, in its final form, below:

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Core;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Core;
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace VideoSamplePlayer
{

    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        int newViewID = 0;

        Window VideoPlayerWindow;

        // To store the reference to the view control, so that it's dispatcher
        //    can be used to schedule more work on its thread.
        CoreApplicationView VideoPlayerView { get; set; }

        // The custom event declaration, to be raised when a media source for the video
        //      is selected.
        public delegate void VideoSelectedHandler(object sender, VideoSelectionArgs e);
        public event VideoSelectedHandler VideoSelected;

        private void RaiseVideoSelectedEvent(MediaSource source)
        {
            // Ensure that something is listening to the event.
            if (this.VideoSelected != null)
            {
                // Create the args, and call the listening event handlers.
                VideoSelectionArgs args = new VideoSelectionArgs(source);
                this.VideoSelected(this, args);
            }
        }

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (newViewID == 0)
            {
                // Store the newly created view control.
                this.VideoPlayerView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();

                await this.VideoPlayerView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                {
                    Frame newFrame = new Frame();
                    newFrame.Navigate(typeof(VideoPlayer), null);

                    // Have the new VideoPlayer page subscribe to the media source selection event on this page.
                    VideoPlayer videoPlayerPage = newFrame.Content as VideoPlayer;
                    this.VideoSelected += videoPlayerPage.VideoSelected;

                    Window.Current.Content = newFrame;
                    Window.Current.Activate();
                    VideoPlayerWindow = Window.Current;

                    newViewID = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
                });

                await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewID, ViewSizePreference.UseMinimum);
            }
        }

        private async void pickFileButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Schedule the work here on the same thread as the VideoPlayer window,
            //    so that it has access to the file and MediaSource to play.
            await this.VideoPlayerView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
            {
                // Create and open the file picker
                FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
                openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
                openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;
                openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");
                openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mkv");
                openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".avi");

                StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
                if (file != null)
                {
                    MediaSource sourceFromFile = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file);

                    // Raise the event declaring that a video was selected.
                    this.RaiseVideoSelectedEvent(sourceFromFile);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // Class definition for the custom event args, which allows a 
    //     media source to be passed to any event handlers that are listening.
    public class VideoSelectionArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public MediaSource Source { get; private set; }

        public VideoSelectionArgs(MediaSource source)
        {
            this.Source = source;
        }
    }
}
```

VideoPlayer.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.Media.Core;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.Pickers;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace VideoSamplePlayer
{
    public sealed partial class VideoPlayer : Page
    {           
        public VideoPlayer()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        // The event handler, which will listen for MainPage's VideoSelected
        //     event, after being subscribed to it on the MainPage.
        public void VideoSelected(object sender, VideoSelectionArgs e)
        {
            // Get the MediaSource from the event arguments, and set up and start
            //    the media player.
            mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.Source = e.Source;
            mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.RealTimePlayback = true;
            mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: This code was tested, by clicking on the "Pick Video" button **AFTER** the second window was opened. You may have to do some more work to make it safe to click prior to the second window being opened (or simply hide it until the second window is opened).